# Do there exist two homogeneous polynomials $P,Q \in \mathbb{C}[z_0,\dots, z_n]$ such that the origin is their only common zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

The title says it all. Thanks in advance! I don't know if the statement is true or not, but it seems to me that any two homogeneous polynomials must intersect in more than just the origin.

EDIT: $P,Q $ have the same degree $d\geq 2$, and $n\geq 2$.

Comment: It's true for any two polynomials if $n\ge 2$, they will have infinitely many common solutions. Maybe "resultant of polynomials" would be of some help.

Comment: for characterisations of the irrelevant ideal also look at Hartshorne, Ex. 2.2 in Chapter 1

Comment: Note that you must assume that $n>2$. Otherwise one may just consider $P = Z_0^2, Q = Z_1^2$. Now, the question boils down to considering whether two hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$ given by $P,Q$ have non-trivial solution. This is just a restatement of the comment above. Now one can use the projective dimension theorem, page 48, theorem 7.2. Also note that being algebraically closed is really important. Look at this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50882/why-is-a-variety-over-a-non-alg-closed-field-a-hypersurface